# How to access newest data in a database while webapplication is in runtime

Tags: javascript, html, database, oracle, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC webapplication which is retrieving data from a DB.
But once the application is run and the data in the database change, the webapplication won't show the newest data. It only shows the data from the time it was built. How can I force my application to always show the newest data?

My JSP is:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TIME</th>
            <th>CITY</th>
            <th>GATE</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <c:forEach items="${flights}" var="flight" begin = "0" end = "5">
           <tr>
               <td>${flight.time}</td>
               <td>${flight.city}</td>
               <td>${flight.gate}</td>
           </tr>
       </c:forEach>
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer to your needs is using Websocket technology.

Here is [an example](http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/04/postgresql-nofify-websocket-spring-mvc.html) using spring and Postgresql, and [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) is official attempt to use that technology (spring-stomp).

Comment: how can new data be found? we should have date_time (timestamp) column in DB tables. which will have the time value of row inserted row updated time. Then client application has to use  date_time column in SQL where clause.